# Python Thread not not treating GTK spinner properly

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, pygtk, python-multithreading

I have 2 simple threads in my PYGTK desktop application. Thread1 - Start spinner to show work in progress of heavy process Thread2 - A heavy process

I start Thread1 first it gets completely executed first but spinner does not start. Spinner starts when my Thread2 ends. I dont understand why spinner is not starting before heavy process.

Code is like this...

```
def StartSpinner(self):
  spinner.start()
  print('Thread1 complete')

def HeavyProcess(self):
  Statement1
  Statement4
  Statement3
  Statement4
  print('Thread2 complete')


if __name__ == '__main__':

        t1=threading.Thread(target=self.StartSpinner)
        t2=threading.Thread(target=self.HeavyProcess)

        t1.start()
        t1.join()

        t2.start()
        t2.join()

Output : 
Thread1 complete
Thread2 complete
```

Output is correct but Gtk Spinner is starting after heavy process ends. Whatever sequence of thread is given,Spinner only start after complete execution of Thread2.

Comment: Two things to be wary of when dealing with multithreading, python, and GUI libraries: 1. GIL which prevents more than one thread executing Python code at the time, 2. blocking event loop prevents GTK from redrawing

Comment: Yeah, does GTK+ mainloop run in the main thread? `t2.join()` blocks it...

Comment: You guys are right. I am running loop in Thread2. If i remove this thread,problem gets solved. Many thanks. Please guide if you know anything about dealing with loop also.